# Tcl/Tk: limiting the resize `text` widget

Tags: text, tcl, widget, tk-toolkit

I have question on limiting the resizing the `text` `Tk` widget. I have the following code with two `text` widgets lined up on top of each other. The problem is when I resize the text widget containing "Box2" just disappears as shown in images below.

I want to do resizing such that "Box2" is also seen. If at certain stage of resizing if "Box2" can't be shown then resizing to a smaller size should be disallowed (though resizing to a bigger size should be allowed).

Normal size[image: This the normal sized one]

Resized [image: Here "Box2" text widget disappears]

The code to reproduce the problem is:

```
#----------------------------------------------
# scrolled_text from Brent Welch's book
#----------------------------------------------
proc scrolled_text { f args } {
    frame $f
    eval {text $f.text -wrap none \
        -xscrollcommand [list $f.xscroll set] \
        -yscrollcommand [list $f.yscroll set]} $args
    scrollbar $f.xscroll -orient horizontal \
        -command [list $f.text xview]
    scrollbar $f.yscroll -orient vertical \
        -command [list $f.text yview]
    grid $f.text $f.yscroll -sticky news
    grid $f.xscroll -sticky news
    grid rowconfigure $f 0 -weight 1
    grid columnconfigure $f 0 -weight 1
    return $f.text
}


proc horiz_scrolled_text { f args } {
    frame $f
    eval {text $f.text -wrap none \
        -xscrollcommand [list $f.xscroll set] } $args
    scrollbar $f.xscroll -orient horizontal -command [list $f.text xview]
    grid $f.text -sticky news
    grid $f.xscroll -sticky news
    grid rowconfigure $f 0 -weight 1
    grid columnconfigure $f 0 -weight 1 
    return $f.text
}
set st1 [scrolled_text .t1 -width 40 -height 10]
set st2 [horiz_scrolled_text .t2 -width 40 -height 2]

pack .t1 -side top -fill both -expand true
pack .t2 -side top -fill x 

$st1 insert end "Box1"
$st2 insert end "Box2"
```

Comment: Try using `grid` instead of pack with .t1/.t2 and than set the weight/and or minsize option on the rows/columns. See http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html for some more about grid.

Comment: @schlenk Thanks for the tip. It works. I will post the working code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grid` instead of `pack` as suggested by schlenk works.

```
set st1 [scrolled_text .t1 -width 80 -height 40]
set st2 [horiz_scrolled_text .t2 -width 80 -height 2]

grid .t1 -sticky news
grid .t2 -sticky news

# row 0 - t1; row 1 - t2
grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 10  -minsize 5
grid rowconfigure . 1 -weight 2   -minsize 1
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1

$st1 insert end "Box1"
$st2 insert end "Box2"
```

The key here is `rowconfigure` and the weight's assigned to it. I have assigned `10` to `.t1` and `2` to `.t2` in accordance to their `height` values. I have also set the `minsize` to `5` and `1` so that we do not shrink the window beyond a certain minimum.

The `columnconfigure` has `weight` set to `1` because if we try to resize horizontally the windows should expand and fill instead of leaving empty spaces.